# How to add in space escape for $PWD

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I want to use

```
ln -s $PWD ~/mylinkname
```

But the problem I'm facing is that my current path has space (therefore ln cannot execute correctly).

I believe the solution should be simply but I searched over cannot find answer.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A practical advice on Linux and other Unixes is to avoid space in file (or directory) paths

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your argument has spaces, it will treat each space-delimited portion as a separate argument.

To prevent this, quote any arguments that have spaces, eg:

```
ln -s "$PWD" "$HOME/my link name with spaces"
```

If the filename has quotes, you can also escape it with a backslash

```
ln -s "$PWD" "$HOME/my link name with spaces and this quote\""
```

Instead of $HOME, you can use:

```
ln -s "$PWD" ~/"my link name with spaces"
```

Comment: Well, I originally assumed to OP would be able to work it out after I explained that quoting it allows it to have spaces.

Comment: You need `$HOME` instead of `~`

Comment: Thx, I saw your comment on the other answer.

Comment: You can use `~` too, but `~/` must be outside the quotes.  `~/"my link with spaces"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
ln -s "$PWD" "$HOME/mylinkname"
```

should do it.

Comment: I would suggest using `$HOME` instead of `~`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You're right, turns out `~` doesn't work in quotes.